# I've a good graphic card but if I change the quality at YouTube it still stays the same

Tags: google-chrome, video, graphics-card, performance, youtube

I am having an issue with the quality of videos or browser games, I guess.

The issue happends as example at agar.io that its first smooth and later it looks like 50 fps or something like and later it gets better again.
The issue also happends at YouTube when I change the quality to 1080p I don't see any differences or any better quality.

I have two graphics card one is Intel HD Graphics and the other one is Nvidia.
I've heard there is a Nvidia control panel.
I don't have graphic issues ingame.
I am using the Chrome browser.

[chrome://gpu/ The GL_Renderer results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpwAC.png)

Whats the problem?

Comment: Your laptop is probably overheating and then going into a thermal throttling mode. Open it up and clear out the dust or get a cooling mat.

Comment: As stated, it could be heat related as laptops are so small they heat up fast and heat slows everything down. Another factor could be the video quality that was uploaded on the user's page. Even a 1080p upload can look bad. Streaming wireless can be a factor because wireless tends to be slower especially when dealing with interference that you're not aware of. And the settings on your router could be a factor. Troubleshooting can be an in depth challenge for a person not really delved into technology. But if you Google the things I've noted you can fix it. Try a Cable connection too for start.

Comment: I have a cooling mat and there is not dust inside don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

The quality you see depends on many factors

1. **Video card** (though not so much)
2. **Monitor/Display**
3. **Internet  connection** (especially on sites like YouTube)

Almost all video cards nowadays support good quality of resolution

If your Monitor has a lower dpi(dot per inch), you will have to upgrade to see better quality of images on your monitor.

YouTube automatically optimizes the quality of video in accordance with your internet speed. If you have a low Internet speed, You will have to change YouTube settings to increase the resolution.

Comment: Yes but how I change the graphic card?

Comment: @jepjep40 Yes you can easily change the graphic card, if you have a desktop pc

Comment: I mean via nvidia control panel

Comment: @jepjep40 if youhave a laptop, it will be difficult. I hope that clears up your question :)

Comment: go to nvidias website to download the nvidia control pane;

Comment: I already have it and changed the graphic card but I am not sure if I see differences at my opinion the nvidia graphic card helped.

Comment: Is there a way where I can change the graphic cards at a site I choose?

Comment: You cannot **change** a graphic card for sites. Graphic card is a piece of **hardware** which is inside your computer. All you can do is **configure** it with _nvidia control panel_

Comment: Okay my issue I guess the video was made bad because I compare my phone with youtube and I see no differences means that the quality is definitely on 1080p60 with the best that the phone and youtube can get.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARDpMlGZoDg

Comment: I was trying to look 1080p60 and see if good quality is extremly good do you also see it like this?

Comment: I see it in amazing quality, so is your issue solved :) @jepjep40

Comment: Not sure how you see it.